# Alternate of any_number_of_times method in stubs

Tags: mocking, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, rspec-rails, stubs

I have upgraded my project to rails 4 but now I am getting some deprecation warnings and one of them is **DEPRECATION: any_number_of_times is deprecated.**. Code for which I am gettings this warning is

```
sponsorship = RSpec::Mocks::Mock.new(:sponsorship)

SPONSORSHIP.should_receive(:[]).with('sponsorship').any_number_of_times.and_return(sponsorship)
```

and another scenario is

```
sponsorship.should_receive(:[]).with(key).any_number_of_times.and_return(value)
```

I have used stub for above code but it is not stubbing correctly. Can you find where I am doing it wrong. For stubbing I have used

```
SPONSORSHIP.stub(:[]).with('sponsorship').and_return(sponsorship)
```

Comment: Just a hunch, remove the `any_number_of_times` it makes sense that the should_receive would default to at least once.

Comment: removing any_number_of_times gives errors

expected n* times
got one time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `any_number_of_times` is deprecated (and is going away in RSpec 3) because it's not really testing anything. It will never fail, since it can be called 0 times as well. See extended argument in https://trello.com/c/p2OsobvA/78-update-website-menu-architecture-to-accommodate-pledging-as-well-as-weddings-memorials-etc.

If you expect it to be called at least once, you can use `at_least(1).times`.

Comment: I've got a "Card not found" on this link.

Answer (score 3):

Since **`any_number_of_times`** is not of any help other alternative methods like **`at_least(n)`** and **`at_most(n)`** helped removing those deprecation warnings.